# What 's wrong with my merge sort code

Tags: c

I am learning to code and I though I'd try writing a merge sort algorithm (something we heard about in our analytic course but NOT homework). I was working from the pseudo code the trainer showed us but I cannot identify the problem. Any chance someone could point me in the right direction?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef int T;


void merge(T _elem[], int lo, int mi, int hi)
{
    int lb = mi - lo, lc = hi - mi;


    T* B = (T* )malloc(sizeof(T)*lb);

    for (int i = 0; i < lb; i++) B[i] = _elem[i];


    T* C = _elem + mi;


    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; j < lb || k < lc;)
    {
        if (j < lb && (lc <= k || B[j] <= C[k])) _elem[i++] = B[j++];
        if (k < lc && (lb <= j || C[k] < B[j])) _elem[i++] = C[k++];
    }
    free(B);
}

void mergeSort(T _elem[], int lo, int hi)
{
    if (hi - lo < 2) return;
    int mi = (lo + hi) >> 1;
    mergeSort(_elem, lo, mi);
    mergeSort(_elem, mi, hi);
    merge(_elem, lo, mi, hi);
}

int main()
{
    T elem[19] = {53, 130, 120, 14, 206, 31, 380, 39, 402, 146, 491, 51, 54, 59, 722, 79, 82, 186, 92};
    mergeSort(elem, 0, 19);
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
        printf("%d\t", elem[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give an example of the problem. Does it sort wrongly, does it not sort at all, what is the expected output, any errors, etc.

Comment: You forgot to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 glaring issues with this code, but keep in mind I've only read it on my way out, no debugger. You should just debug it and see.

- your `mergeSort()` calls are overlapping in range. There's no reason to sort the middle element twice, plus you want to get rid of elements as fast as possible and end up with an empty set.
- when you fill up your `B` temporary array, you don't index `_elem` right, you should be offsetting by `i+lo` instead.
- same as above, when merging you don't index `_elem` right. You should initialize `i` with `lo`, not start from the beginning all the time.

Comment: I think, the first issue is not right: `hi` is exclusive, so the calls are not overlapping.

Comment: Far be it for me to disagree, but if you have 2, 3 and 4 in `lo`, `mi` and `hi`, `lb` and `lc` will both be 1. Now you can pretend 1 means 1 item, or you can pretend it means 2 items (0 and 1), but either way you have a problem: your sequence has 3 items and you're either processing 2 or 4. I'm sure you know best though.

Comment: Every left limit is inclusive, every right limit is exclusive. So in your example lo=2, mi=3 means a sequence of 1 item at index 2, mi=3, hi=4 means a sequence of 1 item at index 3, lo=2, hi=4 means a sequence of 2 items at indexes 2 and 3. It all works out (unless there are off-by-1 errors in code).